# Amazon DynamoDB Json support while querying and scanning

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

After a painful day trying to figure out if we should go with DynamoDB to store Json documents (vs mongo) and reading through almost all the AWS documentations and online examples, I have decided to ask my questions here.

Ours is a Spring Boot Java application and we are using the aws-dynamodb sdk plugin. Our application has to manage a couple of thousands of Json documents and be able to retrieve based on various conditions.

For example, imagine this is the JSon document -

```
{ 
"serial":"123123",
"feed":{
      "ABC":{
          "queue": "ABC",
          "active": true
            },
       "XYZ" : {
           "queue":"XYZ",
           "active": false
 }
}
```

These are the questions I have

1. Can I store this whole Json document as a String attribute in Dynamo table and still be able to retrieve the records based on the value of certain attributes inside the Json and how?
   For example I would like to get all the items that has the feed ABC active.
2. How scalable is this solution?

I know I can do this very easily in Mongo but just couldn't get it working in dynamo.

Answer (score 1):

First, if you aren't using [DynamoDBMapper](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) for talking to DynamoDB, you should consider using it, instead of low-level APIs, as it provides a more convenient higher-level abstraction.

Now, answers to your questions:

- Instead of storing it as a String, consider using Map. More information on supported data types can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes). As for searching, there are [two ways](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html): `Query` (in which you need to provide primary keys of the records you need) and `Scan`. For your example (i.e. 'all the items that has the feed ABC active'), you'd have to do a `Scan`, as you don't know the primary keys.
- DynamoDB is highly scalable. `Query`ing is efficient, but looks like you'll be `Scan`ing more. The latter has its limitations, as it literally goes through each record, but should work fine for you as you'll only have couple of thousand records. Do performance testing first though.